# How to keep GKMatch connection alive

Tags: ios, game-center, multiplayer, gamekit

I have a game, working with GameKit and using the Apple Game Center to manage the connection and messages.

When I am testing the software there is no issue with the connection, but once I am playing with another user over the internet the player is very often disconnected suddenly.

I would like to implement a simple method to reconnect the player or avoid to get the disconnected state from Game Center.

I was trying the solutions suggested at several forums and by the iOS documentation too, but all these are operating with sending a re-invite message to the user which is not really a nice solution.

I would like to have something like automatically waiting for the other user at least for 30 seconds or a minute before the game would tell that the player is disconnected finally.

Sometimes the disconnected message is coming very quickly after a normal data message, sent by the game itself, so it is not really clear why this happens.

Could someone has a good solution for this issue?